# ImmutableJS Map or OrderedMap change position

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have `Map` and `OrderedMap` objects. 
I need to key different then 0,1,2 this is why I don't use `List`.
But I need to add arrows to move up/down elements in this list. Also it would be good to set "insert after" not only as last element.

I know that it sounds like I need to `List`, but too many function based on keys different than 0,1,2 to change this objects.

Any hints how can I move elements inside this kind of elements?

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: just add a sort order variable, and use that to sort into array when you wish to render. or sort.

Comment: you mean something like `immutable.get('items').sortBy(item => item.position)`?
When I'll remove position from 1 I have should change position value from others. To keep 1,2,3,4 not any numbers. 
Or when I'll move from 3 to 4 position I have to search all list. Do you think that it will ok from efficiency point of view?

Comment: whut? if you have 1,2,3,4 and you remove 2, then they will still sort in order, 1,3,4 ?You do not need to change the others.

Comment: But then If I'd like move 4 up I need to check what index is before and search all list

Comment: yes. Usually what one does is record current pos, get next pos next to it, swap the two, finished. `x:1,y:2,z:3 => moveup(x) => x:2,y:1,z:3 => moveup(x) => x:3,y:1,z:2`, and repeat that as often as neccesary to move it to the correct position.

Answer (score 1):

So let say you have a map like this

```
fromJS({
  saturn: 'planet',
  earth: 'planet,
  sun: 'star'
})
```

You can use

```
immutable.get('items')
  .keySeq()
  .indexOf("earth")

// returns 1
```

The result will be the index if the Map were a List or Array. -1 would be returned if not found.

On the other hand, if you need to find the map key with the index, you can do this:

```
immutable.get('items')
  .keySeq()
  .findIndex(k => k === 1)

// returns "earth"
```